# cannot download data files using Java

Tags: java, file, sockets, stream

I need to download a file using Java. I can use this code to download text files. But I have a problem downloading image[data] files. They are written in to the disk corrupted. What have I done here wrong?

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(url
                .getPath().substring(url.getPath().lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
String line = "";
long l = 0;
while (!(line = bufferedReader.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(line);
    if (line.contains("Content-Length:")) {
        l = Long.parseLong(line.substring(
                "Content-Length:".length()).trim());
    }
}

byte[] bytes = new byte[socket.getSendBufferSize()];
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));
int x = 0;
long fullLength = 0;
int length = 0;
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
        socket.getInputStream());
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
        fileOutputStream);
while (fullLength < l
        && (length = dataInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    dataOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, length);

    System.out.print(length + " ");
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    fullLength += length;
}

fileOutputStream.flush();
bufferedWriter.close();
socket.close();
```

Comment: Hm, mixing the use of Readers (especially buffered ones that may read ahead) and the underlying Streams feels like it may be your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to download a binary file using HTTP protocol. This can actually be done in much easier way:

```
final URL url = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Giewont_and_Wielka_Turnia.jpg");  //1
final InputStream input = url.openStream();  //2
final OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("giewont.jpg")); //3
IOUtils.copy(input, output);  //4
input.close();  //5
output.close();
```

In steps:

1. Create `URL` pointing to a resource you want to download.
2. `openStream()` to read the file byte-by-byte. The underlying `URL` implementations handles sockets, `Content-length`, etc.
3. Create an empty file to save data to.
4. Copy the contents of `input` to `output`. I am using [`IOUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from Apache [`commons-io`](http://commons.apache.org/io/) to avoid boring and error-prone copying in a loop.
5. Close both streams. You need to close the `input` to close the actual socket (maybe it happens implicitly once the streams ends?) and `output` to flush the buffers.
6. ...that's it!

Note that since you are basically copying the data byte-by-byte, both text files (irrespective to encoding) and binary files are transferred correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Copying byte by byte solved the problem. I thought buffering is always the best choice. Thanks again.